# linuxefi causes "you need to load kernel first"

Tags: centos, grub2, grub, pxe

I am aware of the multiple questions regarding this matter but this one seems to be different. This is the Grub configuration our PXE boot server provides:

```
net_ls_addr
sleep -i 5
set retcode=$?
clear

if [ $retcode == 1 ]; then
 quit
fi

if [ $retcode == 0 ]; then
 quit
fi

if [ $retcode == 3 ]; then
 terminal_output gfxterm
 set gfxmode="800x600;640x480;auto"
 set theme=theme.txt
fi

menuentry 'Install Custom CentOS 7 Linux x86_64 (CC7)' {
 insmod progress
 clear
 #set net_default_server=linuxsofturl
 echo -n 'loading kernel ...'
 linuxefi (http)/aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.repo=http://linuxsofturl/centos/7/os/x86_64/
 clear
 echo -n 'loading initrd ...'
 initrdefi (http)/aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/initrd
}
```

This, as mentioned, causes a "you need to load the kernel first". Until now it was working fine.
To add further background, the following menu entries used to work until two weeks ago:

```
menuentry 'Install CentOS 8 Linux x86_64 (C8)' {
 insmod progress
 clear
 echo -n 'loading kernel ...'
 linuxefi /aims/boot/C8_X86_64/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.repo=http://linuxsofturl/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ inst.addrepo=CUSTOM,http://linuxsofturl/centos/8/CUSTOM/x86_64/ inst.addrepo=locmap,http://linuxsofturl/internal/repos/potd8-stable/x86_64/os/ ks=http://linuxsofturl/linux/centos8/default.ks
 clear
 echo -n 'loading initrd ...'
 initrdefi /aims/boot/C8_X86_64/initrd
}

menuentry 'Install Custom CentOS 7 Linux x86_64 (CC7)' {
 insmod progress
 clear
 #set net_default_server=linuxsofturl
 echo -n 'loading kernel ...'
 linuxefi (http)/aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/vmlinuz ip=dhcp inst.repo=http://linuxsofturl/centos/7/os/x86_64/
 clear
 echo -n 'loading initrd ...'
 initrdefi (http)/aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/initrd
}

menuentry 'Install Scientific Linux Custom 6 x86_64 (SLC6)' {
 insmod progress
 clear
 echo -n 'loading kernel ...'
 linux (http)/aims/boot/SLC6X_X86_64/vmlinuz ip=dhcp repo=http://linuxsofturl/slc6X/x86_64/
 clear
 echo -n 'loading initrd ...'
 initrd (http)/aims/boot/SLC6X_X86_64/initrd
}

menuentry 'Install RHEL 8.2 x86_64 (license required)' {
  insmod progress
  clear
  echo -n 'loading kernel ...'
  linux (http)/aims/boot/RHEL_8_2_X86_64/vmlinuz ip=dhcp repo=http://linuxsofturl/enterprise/rhel/server/8/8.2/x86_64/
  clear
  echo -n 'loading initrd ...'
  initrd (http)/aims/boot/RHEL_8_2_X86_64/initrd
 }
```

It seems that either using `linux` + (http) or `linuxefi` without HTTP protocol (so it will use TFTP, which will be slow) seems to do the trick, but this has always worked until now for a reason.

EDIT: As a sidenote, this is the log output from the TFTP server, note the partial content 206 HTTP error:

```
2020-09-14T15:06:36.618691+02:00 aimstest01 httpd: 128.142.32.27 - - [14/Sep/2020:15:06:36 +0200] "GET /aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/vmlinuz HTTP/1.1" 200 6762688 114153 "-" "GRUB 2.02~beta2"
2020-09-14T15:07:11.137769+02:00 aimstest01 httpd: 128.142.32.27 - - [14/Sep/2020:15:06:37 +0200] "GET /aims/boot/CC7_X86_64/vmlinuz HTTP/1.1" 206 6762688 34080353 "-" "GRUB 2.02~beta2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP as protocol implies that if the KeepAliveTimeout is longer than Grub's timeout, kernel download will timeout, failing with the aforementioned error. Reducing this value on the Apache configuration does the trick.